# Reducing tons of itty bitty HTTP Requests

Tags: http, optimization, request

I've seen in our web app through the network panel in Firebug that there is dozens of small .js file requests (less than 500 bytes often). Same with images.

Is there some nice super awesome technology that solves this problem? Wouldn't it be much faster to have all these files in one http request? I remember reading once that gmail speed up the initial load by some huge factor by lowering the number of HTTP requests done for resources like images and scripts.

Thanks SO for any resources!

Comment: better post your server setup. there are many components out there that can join together css and js files. for images, take a look at css sprites

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any super awsome technology that could solve the problem like that... 
Just combine all of the js files into one or two, and combine the images into [css sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). Google uses sprites a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) to combine all your JS files into one, minifying them at the same time. Just specify more than one input file on the command-line (i.e. multiple `--js` options).